# In a large directory of org-mode files, is there a view that combines them?

Tags: org-mode

I'm looking into better ways to organize my notes in org-mode.  I have a directory full of org-mode files.  Some in lower directories.  I'd like to view them all and add cross references, but I don't really want to have a bunch of open files to have to navigate between.

I could use links and that would make jumping to a target fairly easy, but not then jumping back.

I could use includes, but I'm not really interested in exporting the files, just traversing and walking references.

Is there a feature to org-mode that I'm overlooking, or a tool for this kind of use?  I admit I haven't really concentrated ever on how I organize my org mode files, I just use grep like tools as needed.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [org-roam](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam), which creates a database of links between org files. Specifically, it can create a graph of your notes (see below) which you can use to jump between them.

This also solves your issue of not being able to jump back to the file quickly, as org-roam provides a buffer with files linking to the current file (backlinks).
[image: An org-buffer with a side-panel displaying links]

You can also use [nroam](https://github.com/NicolasPetton/nroam) to show them at the bottom of the buffer instead (I prefer this.)
[image: An org-buffer with a second heading called "backlinks"]

It additionally allows you to create graphs of said links using `org-roam-graph` (but it's kind of clunky.) [image: A directed graph of labels of org-files]

or [org-roam-server](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam-server)

[[image: View of org-roam-server4]

If you configure `org-protocol` you will be able to click the links in the graphs and have it open the corresponding org-file in emacs!

Comment: NB: Nroam is to be used in addition to org-roam, it is not a standalone package.